# Spock test - RESTClient: HttpResponseException: Not Found

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot, spock, httpbuilder

I want to write a test for a GET request when the API returns 404.

My test:

```
   def "Should return 404 - object deleted before"() {
        setup:
        def advertisementEndpoint = new RESTClient( 'http://localhost:8080/' )
        when:
        def resp = advertisementEndpoint.get(
                path: 'api/advertisement/1',
                contentType: groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON
        )
        then:
        resp.status == 404
    }
```

My error:

> 14:24:59.294 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient -
>   Connection can be kept alive indefinitely 14:24:59.305 [main] DEBUG
>   groovyx.net.http.RESTClient - Response code: 404; found handler:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@312aa7c 14:24:59.306 [main]
>   DEBUG groovyx.net.http.RESTClient - Parsing response as:
>   application/json 14:24:59.443 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  <<
>   "ba[\r][\n]" 14:24:59.444 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  <<
>   "{"timestamp":1436358299234,"status":404,"error":"Not
>   Found","exception":"com.pgssoft.exparo.web.ResourceNotFoundException","message":"No
>   message available","path":"/api/advertisement/1"}" 14:24:59.445 [main]
>   DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "[\r][\n]" 14:24:59.445 [main] DEBUG
>   org.apache.http.wire -  << "0[\r][\n]" 14:24:59.446 [main] DEBUG
>   org.apache.http.wire -  << "[\r][\n]" 14:24:59.446 [main] DEBUG
>   o.a.h.i.c.BasicClientConnectionManager - Releasing connection
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@2ab4bc72
>   14:24:59.446 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.BasicClientConnectionManager -
>   Connection can be kept alive indefinitely 14:24:59.449 [main] DEBUG
>   groovyx.net.http.RESTClient - Parsed data to instance of: class
>   groovy.json.internal.LazyMap
>
> groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Not Found     at
>   groovyx.net.http.RESTClient.defaultFailureHandler(RESTClient.java:263)
>     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)   at
>   groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$1.handleResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:503)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:218)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:160)
>     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:515)     at
>   groovyx.net.http.RESTClient.get(RESTClient.java:119)  at
>   AdvertisementTest.Should return 404 - object delete
>   before(AdvertisementTest.groovy:79)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a *failure handler* for the underlying `HTTPBuilder`. From the [`HTTPBuilder` javadoc](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder/0.7.1/groovyx/net/http/HTTPBuilder.java?av=f):

> You can also set a default response handler called for any status code
>   399 that is not matched to a specific handler. Setting the value outside a request closure means it will apply to all future requests
>   with this HTTPBuilder instance:
>
> `http.handler.failure = { resp ->
>       println "Unexpected failure: ${resp.statusLine}" }`

Therefore:

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1')
)

import groovyx.net.*
import groovyx.net.http.*   

def restClient = new RESTClient('http://localhost/wrong')
restClient.handler.failure = { resp -> resp.status }
def response = restClient.get([:])
assert response == 404
```